# Publishing a database created in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, database

I have created a database in SQL Server, and have been able to generate a script.

I want the database saved, so I can use it within my C# app.

How can I recreate or publish this database to a target location? e.g Documents

```
    CREATE TABLE Emails_Log
(
email_Id int,
e_to varchar(255),
e_from varchar(255),
e_Subject varchar(255),
e_date date,
PRIMARY KEY (email_Id)
)
```

I have executed  the above query, and it has created tables in my database, now how do i finish my database so it can be used in other programs?

Where can i find the database file?

Comment: Define target location?
Recreate another Database with that script in SQL server?

Comment: I just want to have this database published so i can use it in my C# application. How do i save it, finish it? make it done?

Comment: Just execute the `CREATE DATABASE....` script in SQL Server Management Studio ...... that creates the database in the SQL Server instance - and you're done. Or what am I missing??

Answer (score 0):

Here at Red Gate we have a new tool, [SQL Connect](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-connect/index-2), that lets you create a Database Project that can be added to your Visual Studio Solution. We're keen to find out what's missing as there are lots of additional features we could add going forward.

One you maintain your database as part of a VS Solution, ideally in source control, you can subsequently deploy it using [SQL Compare Pro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/index-b). This generates a SQL script that has the necessary commands to upgrade an existing database, or create a new one.